# Creating dynamic order basket using php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shopping-cart

I am creating an ePos system, that adds any item user clicks to the basket and calculate the total in the end **all done without total page refresh**.

I tried using $_SESSION and storing as order ( [item] => [price] ) but failed, as i need to refresh.

what I need is:

- to display added Items [id name Qnty price]
- calculate total price of added items.

please advice me on the best method to do this.
thanks

this is what I attempter in javascript

```
function addItem(name, price, id)
                {

                var table=document.getElementById("basket");
                var row=table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
                cell1.innerHTML=name;
                cell2.innerHTML=1;
                cell3.innerHTML=price;
                }
```

but my issue was, i could not find a way to add decimals, parseFloat made alot of bugs for me

Comment: show us what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to refresh the page in order to save information into the PHP Session object.  PHP Session information is stored on the server, so you can do an asynchronous HTTP request to the backend, and store information the PHP Session.  I would suggest using the jQuery.ajax function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do your async HTTP requests.  If you are not familiar with jQuery, I highly suggest you get familiar with it.  I also suggest you look into how AJAX works.

Also, if you are using the PHP session, if you are not using some kind of framework which does session management, you must make sure to call session_start() before using the $_SESSION variable.